# Como criar um novo objeto contendo todos os valores de um objeto inicial mas acrescentando novos atributos em C#

Tags: c#, typescript

Olá, estou com uma dúvida em relação ao C# e a otimização da forma de geração de código. Em Typescript, se eu tenho o código abaixo eu consigo criar um novo objeto a partir de um anterior e, na própria criação desse objeto eu consigo acrescentar ao mesmo novas propriedades, assim:

```
class Foo {
    Bar: string;
    Bin: number;
}

const foo = new Foo();
foo.Bar = 'teste';

const foo2 = {...foo, Bin: 123};
```

em C# eu sou obrigado a definir o foo2 definindo propriedade em propriedade, o que (em minha visão) reduz a velocidade de declaração no código, ficando assim:

```
public class Foo {
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public int Bin { get; set; }
}
public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new Foo() {
           Bar = "teste" 
        };
        var foo2 = new Foo() {
           Bar = foo.Bar,
           Bin = 123
        };
    }
}
```

Nesse exemplo eu tenho somente 1 propriedade, então não é tão ruim para replicar a declaração, mas se eu tenho uma classe com muitas propriedades, isso já fica custoso e cansativo...

Existe alguma forma de que eu possa inferir logo na inicialização de um objeto que o mesmo irá ter as propriedades de outro do mesmo tipo e também ter novas outras propriedades? O que procura seria algo assim:

```
// ... código aqui...
var foo2 = new Foo(){ ...foo, Bin = 123 };
```

Comment: Não entendi, porque até tem um maneira de fazer a passagem de um `array` de informações no C# com a palavra reservada `params`, mas, o seu exemplo não se baseia nisso, poderia editar e colocar um exemplo melhor?

Answer (score 1):

A sintaxe do c# não permite a clonagem e reconhecimento inline do TypeScript `{...foo, Bin: 123};`.

O que dá para fazer é criar um constructor que inicialize alguns membros da classe e que emita um clone usando o método [Object.MemberwiseClone](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.object.memberwiseclone?view=netframework-4.7.2).

```
public class Foo {
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public int Bin { get; set; }

    public Foo(out Foo foo, string bar , int bin) {
       Bar = bar;
       Bin = bin;
       foo = (Foo)this.MemberwiseClone();
    }

}

public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var foo1 = new Foo(out Foo foo2, "PT Stack Overflow", 17) { 
            Bar = "foo1 modificado com sucesso" };
        }

        Console.WriteLine("foo1.Bar = " + foo1.Bar + "| foo2.Bar = " + foo2.Bar);
        Console.WriteLine("foo1.Bin = " + foo1.Bin + "| foo2.Bin = " + foo2.Bin);

    }
}
```

Que resultará em:

```
foo1.Bar = foo1 modificado com sucesso | foo2.Bar = PT Stack Overflow
foo1.Bin = 17 | foo2.Bin = 17
```

Answer (score 0):

Você provavelmente quer usar um parâmetro no construtor:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public int Bin { get; set; }

    // caso ainda não possua uma instância
    public Foo() { }

    public Foo(Foo outro)
    {
        if (outro == null) return;
        Bar = outro.Bar;
        Bin = outro.Bin;
    }
}
```

Caso queira usar algo mais dinâmico, dê uma olhada no [Automapper](https://automapper.org/)